# How to avoid sharepoint to override my CSS classes?

Tags: css, sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013

I'm struggling to avoid that sharepoint overrides my bootstrap classes, but unfortunally without succes, I've tryied many solutions found on the web and also in Sharepoint StackExchange, but no good.

My goal is to add a custom navbar made with bootstrap in the master page. My masterpage is just basically a copy of the Oslo masterpage, I try to attach here some of the code of the page:

```
<head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />       
        <SharePoint:SPPinnedSiteTile runat="server" TileUrl="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png" TileColor="#0072C6" />
        <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server" />
        </SharePoint:PageTitle>
        <SharePoint:StartScript runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15" />

        <SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true" />
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
        <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
<![CDATA[ [if IE 9] ]]>        <style type="text/css">//<![CDATA[
    .ms-core-animation-transparent
    {
        opacity:0;
    }
    .ms-isBot .ms-core-animation-transparent
    {
        opacity:1;
    }


        //]]></style>
<![CDATA[ [endif] ]]>        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">//<![CDATA[
    .ms-core-animation-transparent,
    .ms-core-animation-transparent img
    {
       -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";
    }
    .ms-isBot .ms-core-animation-transparent,
    .ms-isBot .ms-core-animation-transparent img
    {
       -ms-filter:"";
    }
    //]]></style>
    <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            var g_pageLoadAnimationParams = { elementSlideIn: "sideNavBox", elementSlideInPhase2: "contentBox" };


            //]]></script>

        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
        <!-- jQuery -->
            <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/jQuery/jquery.js" runat="server" />
            <!-- jQuery END -->
            <!-- Custom JS References -->
            <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/customJs/masterReorderer.js" runat="server" />
            <!-- Custom JS References END -->
            <!-- CSS & jQuery BOOTSTRAP -->
            <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" runat="server" />
            <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/bootstrap/bootstrap.css%>" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />
            <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css%>" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />

            <!-- CSS BOOTSTRAP & jQuery END -->
```

Where I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing it correctly as you're using SharePoint:CssRegistration and the After property. There are many conflicts between SharePoint's css and Bootstrap, especially when dealing with the box-sizing declaration. You might want to use one of the many free bootstrap themes and masterpages out there:

http://bindtuning.com/cms/umbraco/umbraco-7/theme/thebootstraptheme